# Should I modify this file (/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf) while changing Apache "DocumentRoot directory"?

Tags: server, apache2, php, ssl

I'm wishing to change my Apache **DocumentRoot directory** from `/var/www/html/` to `/path/to/another/directory`. I've modified these files, `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`. May I have to modify `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`?

Without this question, I'm also wishing to know why this file is important? And why should I modify it (if I need to modify it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two files .conf you find in default `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` refers to hosts configurations.

For any host you add in your Apache installation you should edit a .conf file.

Once you edited or added a .conf file you must run `sudo a2ensite [file.conf]` and then `sudo service apache reload` in order to enable your new configuration.

default-ssl.conf refers to a host that use https/ssl encryption.

If you don't use Https hosts you don't need to edit this file.

Comment: Is it okay, if I run `sudo service apache2 restart` in stead of `sudo a2ensite [file.conf]`?

Comment: You must enable the site with a2ensite then you run `service apache2 reload` or `service apache2 restart`.